# Inter-quartile range

Tags: standard-deviation, robust, interquartile

If we have a non-normal distribution say (Weibull)  and we used a robust estimator of standard deviation in term of inter-quartile range (IQR). Is it possible we replace IQR=3*SD?

Comment: What do you mean by replace IQR with 3*SD? IQR = 3rd Quantile - 1st Quantile, and can be very difference from 3*SD. In fact, IQR shows the range of the middle 50% of data, and for the normal distribution, 3*SD is the middle 99.7% of the data.

Answer (score 2):

For a Weibull distribution with shape parameter $\alpha$ and scale parameter $\beta$, the interquartile range and standard deviation have the formulas
\begin{align}
IQR &= \beta\left(\big(\log 4\big)^{1/\alpha}-\big(\log\frac43\big)^{1/\alpha}\right)\\
SD &= \beta\sqrt{\Gamma\big(1+\frac2\alpha\big)-\Gamma^2\big(1+\frac1\alpha\big)}
\end{align}
So for a Weibull distribution the possible range of IQR/SD is from 0 to 1.403, and for large shape parameters $IQR \sim 1.226\, SD$.

[image: plot of IQR/SD vs alpha]